# Updating Text view from CountDownTimer onTick method

Tags: android, android-adapter

I am using a CountDownTimer for displaying the remaining time inside View holder text view.  My code structure is as follows :

```
     Class Demo extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem>
     {        
         ListItemHolder holder=new ListItemHolder();

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           View row = convertView;
           holder.tv= (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_timer);

          //Starting the countdown timer
            return row;
        }

        static class ListItemHolder
        {
            TextView tv;
            ............        
        }         

        public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{

            public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }           

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }

           @Override


            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                   holder.tv.setText("time");
                   }
         }
   }
```

When i try to set the onTick value to the text view inside list item holder, the application throws null pointer exception. Can anyone suggest what I have done wrong here?

Thanks in advance,

Timson

Comment: You have not initialized one of your variables. Either `holder` or `tv`.

Comment: Did you intitialize the tv variable?

Comment: sorry, I didnt include the code, please find the edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if convertView is null and inflate the view if it is null.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if(row==null){
        holder = new ListItemHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
        holder.tv= (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_timer);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ListItemHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    //Starting the countdown timer
    return row;
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for suggestions.  The exception happens from onTick method and not from the getView. I am using the same above code...

Comment: I know, but the problem is that the textview is null on the onTick() because you haven't initialized it on getView(), because row.findViewById(R.id.tv_timer); is probably returning null.

Answer (score 0):

The convertView in getView maybe null

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View row = convertView;
       if (row == null) {
           LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = vi.inflate(R.layout.your layout, null);
          }
       holder.tv= (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_timer);

      //Starting the countdown timer
        return row;
    }
```